# Wine Does Not Work At All for me

Tags: software-installation, wine

I've searched and searched the internet and found a million other people having problems with installing and using wine but nearly no one seems to have the same problem as me and of those that do, the advice given them doesn't seem to do anything to fix the problem for me...

In a nutshell, I install wine. If I do this through the terminal then I get some weird message about gecko being missing (whatever that is). I can find very little information about it and the only thing I did find told me how to install it but when I followed the instructions, I was told it wasn't in the repository to BE installed.

Worse still, when I run winecfg, I get all these errors:

```
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
```

If I install it through the ubuntu package manager, it also doesn't work... I cannot run windows installer .exe's with it and it doesn't appear a context menu item.

I've followed a million tutorials on it through to this point and I can get no further. It doesn't seem to be a functional piece of software. I don't get it... is it just not compatible with ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: How did you install WINE?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1351887/edit) your question and add details of the install and any error messages (copy and paste them in please).  Thank you!

Comment: Wine is not a panacea. It does not work with every Windows application and for those applications that do, they may not work 100% and for those that work 100%, every application is different and the path to getting the application to work is not the same as other apps even similar ones.  For each application you want to work with wine you should research specific instructions for each application.  You may learn that a virtual machine with Windows is a better path. Or even better, find an application developed for Linux/Ubuntu or complain that devs should make their apps cross platform

Comment: @Terrance, I thought I just did that.

Comment: @Nmath, I'm not having problems getting it to run a particular Windows program... I'm not able to make wine, itself, work fullstop. It just throws errors and complains it can't read its own z drive and doesn't appear in the menu when you write click a windows app. It just doesn't work. It's nothing to do with getting any particular program to run under it...

Comment: No, there are a lot of tutorials out there about how to install wine and many/most of them are problematic. If you did anything but `sudo apt install wine` or `wine-stable` we need to know. I'm a long time satisfied wine user from 12.04 to 18.04. I don't get any errors when I run winecfg from the terminal.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question of how you installed it.  All you have there is an error that you get when you run `winecfg`.  You say you followed a million tutorials, but that doesn't tell us anything.  I have installed WINE myself into 20.04 and am not having any issues with it at all.

Comment: @OrganicMarble. I did $ sudo apt-get update $ sudo apt install wine64 $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 $ winecfg

Comment: Why did you install wine64 instead of just wine?  Let me look into the dependencies a little.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Because I'm running a 64-bit edition of Ubuntu and that's what all the tutorials I read said to do. Seemed normal. lol

Comment: OK, I dug up a 20.04 system that had wine installed on it. I'm going to write an answer to the only actual question in your post, but it may not be what you really want.

Comment: @OrganicMarble. Ok. I have uninstalled wine and reinstalled using your syntax. Installation appeared to go fine with your syntax, however, on running winecfg, I get the the same error messages that I listed in the question although wine appears to be installed, I get no option to run with wine, if I right click a windows program. Double clicking does nothing either. I have tried setting file permissions to executable to no avail. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try running your windows program from the terminal with the command `wine [windows-program]`  For example, I run the birding program by cd'ing to the folder the program is in, and then type the command `wine AVISYS60.EXE`

Comment: @OrganicMarble, don't I have to install it on my fake windows first? I tried this anyway. I cd'ed to the folder and ran the wine command on the program. I just got a pause followed by the following error. 0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\LaserGRBL.exe" not found. One of the things which appears to wrong is that wine doesn't seem to be able to write to its own drives. I personally think it's because it doesn't have root privileges but everything I have read tells me not to give it root privileges.

Comment: I am out of ideas as to why you are having so much trouble. I don't "install anything to fake windows" (I don't even know what that means), I just run `wine [windows program]`.  Besides the birding program, I run old games in wine as well. Not everything works.  I hope someone else can help diagnose your issues.

Comment: Me too... Thankyou very much for your help and assistance, @OrganicMarble. :)

Comment: My only other idea is that I keep all the windows programs in `~/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/` It seems like long ago when I started messing with wine, if the .exe files were not in the .wine tree, they wouldn't work. But I don't remember what the errors looked like.

Answer (score 1):

> is it just not compatible with ubuntu 20.04?

It is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04. You can have a working wine install on Ubuntu 20.04 as evidenced by these screenshots.

This shows wine 5.0 running on a 20.04 Ubuntu MATE system.

[image]

This shows the reason for the wine install, an old Windows birding app running under wine.

[image]

To install wine on this system, I issued the single command `sudo apt install wine-stable`.  This resulted in the installation of a *lot* of packages.

Comment: Ok, @Organic Marble. I will uninstall and try your syntax. It might be tomorrow at this point. I'll report back on efficacy on my install. Perhaps it doesn't like Gnome 3, if this is on ubuntu mate?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I finally seem to have this working. :) The terminal is still throwing a few errors after running winecfg but it seems to actually be installed and install and run my windows programs now. The current stable version is 6.0.1. On Ubuntu 20.04, the correct install procedure is reasonably involved and is as follows:

You must uninstall wine and all other wine related apps first. Ie. Wine tricks etc.

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

For other versions of Ubuntu, see official instructions at this link: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu.

A big thankyou to those people who actually genuinely tried to help me. I hope I can return the favour some day. :)